# Find XPath attribute name contains specific string

Tags: xpath

I have `<form data-v-4db188a6="">` tag. 
I need find only form tag contains 'data' **in the attribute name** not attribute value!
`.//form[contains(@prop, 'data')]` not work.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
//form[attribute::*[contains(local-name(), 'data')]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Short ***xpath*** expression:

```
//form/@*[contains(name(), 'data')]
```

Comment: If i use selenium to find an array of elements: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression ".//form/@*[contains(name(), 'data')]" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.

Comment: So i use //form[@*[contains(name(), 'data')]]