# How to extract attribute starting with : with Xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to parse html with xpath in order to extract variants of a product in the form of URL and article ID (pzn). The variants seem to be within an attribute starting with `:variants="[{` followed by json code:

```
response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "productAddToCartPanel")]//app-add-to-cart-form').extract()

['<app-add-to-cart-form action="/cart/add" id="addToCartForm-1" class="addToCartForm col-12" button_label="In den Warenkorb" is_tile="false" product_pzn="09900426" product_has_price="true" product_is_promotional_item="false" follow_product_url="" utm_source="" product_delivery="0" :variants="[{pzn: \'09900426\',url: \'/online-kaufen/bio-h-tin-vit-h-25mg-4woc-tabletten-9900426\',packageSizeValue: \'28\',packageSizeUnit: \'St\',sizeValue: \'\',potency: \'\'},{pzn: \'09900432\',url: \'/online-kaufen/bio-h-tin-vit-h-25mg-12wo-tabletten-9900432\',packageSizeValue: \'84\',packageSizeUnit: \'St\',sizeValue: \'\',potency: \'\'},{pzn: \'09900455\',url: \'/online-kaufen/bio-h-tin-vit-h-25mg-2x12-tabletten-9900455\',packageSizeValue: \'168\',packageSizeUnit: \'St\',sizeValue: \'\',potency: \'\'},]" " active="">\n<input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="f7822125-dc05-48c7-bdae-55fa2f131266">\n<input type="hidden" class="productCodePost" name="productCodePost" value="09900426">\n<input type="hidden" value="09900426" name="ff_id"><input type="hidden" value="Bio-H-Tin Vitamin H 2,5 mg f&amp;uuml;r 4 Wochen Tabletten" name="ff_title"><input type="hidden" value="8.03" name="ff_price"></app-add-to-cart-form>']
```

I am getting a invalid expression error trying to access the variable:

```
response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "productAddToCartPanel")]//app-add-to-cart-form/@":variants"').extract()
```

How can I extract the pzn and url value?

Comment: A document in which an attribute name starts with ":" does not conform to the XPath data model so the behaviour of XPath processors when faced with such a document is undefined. Your results will vary from one XPath processor to another. In most cases, you won't get as far as executing the XPath expression -- parsing of the source document will fail.

Comment: Prophets solution seems to work though.

Comment: How many XPath processors did you try it on?

Comment: Just One. If it works, one is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "productAddToCartPanel")]//app-add-to-cart-form[attribute::*[contains(local-name(), "variants")]]').extract()
```

Or this

```
response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "productAddToCartPanel")]//app-add-to-cart-form/@*[contains(name(), "variants")]').extract()
```

(Or both of them)

Comment: credits to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650002/find-xpath-attribute-name-contains-specific-string :)